# Delete a pod but mark the job as successful

Tags: kubernetes

I have a system that brings up Jobs, each with a Pod that has multiple containers.

Two of those containers are not under my control and run "background"/sidecar daemons. The container I do control is able to run to completion, but once it's done, the Pod is still considered `active` since two of the containers are still up.

I've tried killing the other containers from mine, but that works ~99% of the time and we run a lot of Jobs. When it fails, deleting the Pod (or letting the Job timeout) works, but it marks the Job as a failure rather than as a success, and I use that status to indicate to users the result of their work.

Edit: I'm aware of the "sidecar containers" [KEP](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/753), but no PR has been accepted for it yet, so it's not going to be available in a stable cluster for a very long time.

Comment: what are those sidecar containers? Istio?

Comment: No, they're daemons that are queried by the main container. Analogous to a sqlite3 database, wrapped in an RPC layer to be queried by the main container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know to what extent this answers your question, but it seems that there is an ongoing [discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25908) about sidecar containers, and an [enhancement proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/753) about this also.

An interesting solution proposed in the thread above is this [k8s-controller-sidecars](https://github.com/nrmitchi/k8s-controller-sidecars) proposed by a user, and which seems easy to configure.

Try it out, and let us know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither that controller nor its forks worked out for us. We're still looking for a good solution here, so I'll continue to watch that discussion.